# belongsTo Relation with where condition?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

I need to do a where condition in my query using belongsTo relation

My relation is:

```
 public function user() 
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
 }
```

My query is:

```
Post::with('user')->where('user.blocked', '<>', 1)->orWhere(function($query){
                             $query->where('posts.user_id', '=', ApiParam::get('user_id'))
                                   ->where('followers.following_id', '<>', 'NULL');
                      }) 
                       ->leftJoin('followers', function($join){
                            $join->on('followers.following_id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
                                 ->where('followers.user_id', '=', ApiParam::get('user_id'))
                                 ->where('followers.status', '=', Followers::USER_FOLLOW_STATUS_ACCEPT);
                       })
                        ->select('posts.*')
                        ->orderBy('posts.updated', 'DESC')
                        ->limit(20)
                        ->get();
```

But when a run this, i received the following error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.blocked' in 'where clause'`

How can I use where condition when I use with('') relation in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [Constraining eager loads.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) Something you've already used in your codes.

```
Post::with(['user'=>function($query)
  {
      $query->where('blocked', '<>', 1)
  }])->get();
```